# Logo if statement

Tags: logo-lang, ucb-logo

I am using Logo and I have certain problems while iterating through list. 
What is the problem with the line.

```
if count :L = 0 [stop]
```

The :L is a list. So, I would like to test the length of list and stop after the list is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the count command in parentheses so that it is evaluated first:

```
if (count :L) = 0 [stop]
```

It also wouldn't hurt to add additional parentheses around the entire test and also add the empty brackets for the else clause (if required by your logo interpreter):

```
if ((count :L) = 0) [stop] []
```

Bear in mind, `stop` is used to exit a procedure.  If all you want to do is exit out of a loop, you may want to look at other loop structures like a `for`, `while` or `until` loop.